# Using Angular directives for connect HTML clicks in buttons and controller actions

Tags: javascript, angular.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to improve my Angular directive. I'm pretty new to CoffeeScript, so I think there may be inconsistent code.

```
'use strict'
class Main extends Directive
  constructor: (VerifyService) ->
    return {
      restrict : 'M'
      link : (scope) ->
        scope.watch 'events', ->
          ACTION =
            booking = () ->
              scope.ctrl.create()

          filter = (control) ->
            if ACTION[control]
              ACTION[control]()
            return

          door = () ->
            control = $(this).data('controller-control')
            filter(control)
            return

          init = () ->
            PROP.element.bind('click', door)
            return
          return

          test = () ->
            if VerifyService.each(PROP)
              init()
            return

          test()
          return
    }
```

I'm using directives not only to manipulate the HTML, but to use as a bridge between HTML and CONTROLLERS. Please do not question why I'm doing like this; there is a very big reason.

I'm using the GULP-NG-CLASSIFY, which makes available the use of CoffeeScript class syntax.

Inside of the link function (which all directive have) I'm starting my code from the bottom to the top.

First I test if all my HTML properties are available (in this code I only have one):

```
      test = () ->
        if VerifyService.each(PROP)
          init()
        return

      test()
      return
```

If all the `PROP` exists in the HTML, I want initialize the script, which will bind a click in the `PROP.element`:

```
      init = () ->
        PROP.element.bind('click', door)
        return
      return
```

So, in the door, I want get the data from `data-controller-control`:

```
      door = () ->
        control = $(this).data('controller-control')
        filter(control)
        return
```

I need filter and I want get the controller action requested. I need to be sure that the action in my controller exists:

```
      filter = (control) ->
        if ACTION[control]
          ACTION[control]()
        return
```

Finally I call the `ACTION` requested by the user:

```
      ACTION =
        booking = () ->
          scope.ctrl.create()
```

In this case I only have one.